# How to pass parameters from a URL link to a request?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

**In my Main.tsx:**

```
import React, { FC, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom'

import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from '../../hook'
import { getProducts } from '../../store/ProductsSlice'

import Filter from '../Filter/Filter'
import Pagination from '../Pagination/Pagination'
import Products from '../Products/Products'

import { ErrorMessage, FilterError } from './styled'

const Main: FC = () => {
    const products = useAppSelector((state) => state.products.list)

    const dispatch = useAppDispatch()

    const [errorId, setErrorId] = useState<string>('')
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState<string>('')

    const [page, setPage] = useState<number>(1)
    const [filterId, setFilterId] = useState<number>()

    const [pageParams, setPageParams] = useSearchParams()
    pageParams.get(`page`) || ''
    pageParams.get(`id`) || ''

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchProducts(id?: number, productsPage = 1) {
            const itemsPerPage = 5
            let url: string
            if (id) {
                url = `https://reqres.in/api/products/${id}`
            } else {
                url = `https://reqres.in/api/pr231oducts?per_page=${itemsPerPage}&page=${productsPage}`
            }
            const requestOptions = {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            }

            fetch(url, requestOptions)
                .then(async (response) => {
                    const data = await response.json()
                    if (response.ok) {
                        setErrorId('')
                        setErrorMessage('')
                        if (id) {
                            dispatch(
                                getProducts({
                                    page: 1,
                                    per_page: 1,
                                    total: 1,
                                    total_pages: 1,
                                    data: [data.data],
                                })
                            )
                            setPageParams({ page: `1`, id: `${id}` })
                        } else {
                            dispatch(getProducts(data))
                            setPageParams({ page: `${productsPage}` })
                        }
                    } else {
                        const error = (data && data.message) || response.status
                        return Promise.reject(error)
                    }
                    setErrorMessage(data.id)
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    setErrorId(error.toString())
                    console.error('There was an error!', error)
                })
        }
        fetchProducts(filterId, page)
    }, [filterId, page])

    return (
        <div>
            {!products ? (
                <>
                    {errorId ? <ErrorMessage>{errorId}</ErrorMessage> : null}
                    {errorMessage ? (
                        <ErrorMessage>
                            Something went wrong
                            {errorMessage}
                        </ErrorMessage>
                    ) : null}
                </>
            ) : (
                <>
                    <Filter setFilterId={setFilterId} />
                    {errorId ? (
                        <FilterError>
                            {errorId}:
                            {errorId === '404'
                                ? ' Product not found'
                                : `${errorId}: ${errorMessage}`}
                        </FilterError>
                    ) : (
                        <Products />
                    )}

                    <Pagination setPage={setPage} />
                </>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Main
```

**Filter.tsx:**

```
import React, { FC } from 'react'

import { FilterContainer, FilterInput } from './styled'

const Filter: FC<{
    setFilterId: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number | undefined>>
}> = ({ setFilterId }) => {
    return (
        <FilterContainer>
            <FilterInput
                onChange={(e) => {
                    if (e.target.value === '0') {
                        e.target.value = ''
                    }
                    setFilterId(Number(e.target.value))
                }}
                placeholder="Search by id"
                type="number"
            />
        </FilterContainer>
    )
}

export default Filter
```

**Pagination.tsx:**

```
import { FC } from 'react'
import { useAppSelector } from '../../hook'

import ArrowBackIosIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowBackIos'
import ArrowForwardIosIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowForwardIos'

import { PaginationBtn, PaginationContainer } from './styled'

const Pagination: FC<{
    setPage: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>
}> = ({ setPage }) => {
    let pageNumber = useAppSelector((state) => state.products.list.page)
    const totalPages = useAppSelector((state) => state.products.list.total_pages)

    return (
        <PaginationContainer>
            <PaginationBtn
                onClick={() => {
                    setPage((pageNumber -= 1))
                }}
                disabled={pageNumber <= 1}
            >
                <ArrowBackIosIcon fontSize="large" />
            </PaginationBtn>

            <PaginationBtn
                onClick={() => {
                    setPage((pageNumber += 1))
                }}
                disabled={pageNumber >= totalPages}
            >
                <ArrowForwardIosIcon fontSize="large" />
            </PaginationBtn>
        </PaginationContainer>
    )
}

export default Pagination
```

*The fetchProducts function makes a request to the API, using the productPage and id variables passed to the function, the corresponding request is sent and the necessary information is displayed on the screen.
I'm going to take the page and id from the link and pass them to the fetchProducts function so that if something happens, the site opens immediately with the necessary information.*

*I have useSearchParams() with which I make a link that can be "sent to other users". But I don’t understand how to implement that when parameters are inserted into the link, they are applied and the page with the necessary data is loaded.*

Now the correct link is generated, but if you copy it and paste it in another browser window, the standard "list of products" will be loaded

Comment: The `useSearchParams` hook doesn't generate links, it returns a `URLSearchParams` object and updater function that updates the queryString parameters. What page are you trying to read the query params and apply them? What do they need to be applied to? Can you [edit] the post to include clearer details and what the issue is?

Comment: @DrewReese I updated the post, tried to describe what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Are you asking, or saying, that `fetchProducts` in `Main` needs to, or should, read the queryString params and make the appropriate network request?

Comment: @DrewReese fetchProducts should take the parameters from the URL link and make the appropriate request

Comment: So use the ```pageParams.get(`page`) || ''``` and ```pageParams.get(`id`) || ''``` that is referenced in the component to make the network request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

The `Main` component has competing "sources of truth", the queryString params and local state.

## Solution

Use the queryString params as the source of truth for the API requests. Access the `"page"` and `"id"` query params in the component and pass as `useEffect` hook dependencies and on to the `fetchProducts` handler. Instead of enqueuing state updates enqueue navigation redirects that only update the URL queryString.

```
const Main: FC = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const products = useAppSelector((state) => state.products.list);

  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

  // Read the queryString parameters, convert to number type
  const page = Number(searchParams.get("page") || 1);
  const filterId = Number(searchParams.get("id"));
    
  const [errorId, setErrorId] = useState<string>('');
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState<string>('');
```

```
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchProducts(id?: number, page: number = 1) {
      const itemsPerPage = 5;
      const url = id
        ? `https://reqres.in/api/products/${id}`
        : `https://reqres.in/api/pr231oducts?per_page=${itemsPerPage}&page=${page}`;

      const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      }

      try {
        const response = await fetch(url, requestOptions);
        const data = await response.json();
      
        if (response.ok) {
          setErrorId('');
          setErrorMessage('');

          if (id) {
            dispatch(
              getProducts({
                page: 1,
                per_page: 1,
                total: 1,
                total_pages: 1,
                data: [data.data],
              })
            );
            setSearchParams({ page, id }, { replace: true });
          } else {
            dispatch(getProducts(data));
            setPageParams({ page }, { replace: true });
          }
        } else {
          const error = data?.message || response.status;
          return Promise.reject(error);
        }
        setErrorMessage(data.id);
      } catch(error) {
        setErrorId(error.toString());
        console.error('There was an error!', error);
      }
    };

    fetchProducts(filterId, page);
  }, [filterId, page]);
```

```
  // Callbacks to update the queryString parameters
  const setPage = page => setSearchParams(params => {
    params.set("page", page);
    return params;
  }, { replace: true });

  const setFilterId = id => setSearchParams(params => {
    params.set("id", id);
    return params;
  }, { replace: true });
```

```
  return (
    <div>
      {!products ? (
        <>
          {errorId ? <ErrorMessage>{errorId}</ErrorMessage> : null}
          {errorMessage && (
            <ErrorMessage>
              Something went wrong
              {errorMessage}
            </ErrorMessage>
          )}
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <Filter setFilterId={setFilterId} />
          {errorId ? (
            <FilterError>
              {errorId}:
              {errorId === '404'
                ? "Product not found"
                : `${errorId}: ${errorMessage}`
              }
            </FilterError>
          ) : (
            <Products />
          )}

          <Pagination setPage={setPage} />
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I have already an exemple for make you understand How to pass parameters from a URL link to a request:

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/add-book" element={<AddBook />} />
        <Route path="/upd-book/:id" element={<UpdBook />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

**Home.js**

```
<Link to={`/upd-book/${id}`} >Update</Link>
```

**UpdatePage.js** exemple url after you click to Link: localhost:3000/upd-book/30

```
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom';

const {id} = useParams();
```

{id} is 30

I hope this exemple explain how this is work.